# Mongo call leading to node js memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, memory-leaks

When I run `await Order.find({})`, which returns 22k documents, the `used_heap_size` goes up to around 430mb from around 50mb.

It never seems to go back down.

Shouldn't the `used_heap_size` go back down pretty soon? I'm not sure if this is defined as a memory leak, but it seems like it. What causes this? Is this normal?

```js
  app.get('/orders', async (req, res, next) => {
    v8Print('before find orders');
    const j = await Order.find({});
    v8Print('afters find orders');
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
  app.get('/logMem', async (req, res, next) => {
    v8Print('memory info');

    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```

Log function

```js
const v8 = require('v8');

// for memory allocation heap debugging
module.exports.v8Print = (message) => {
  const heapStats = v8.getHeapStatistics();
  const heapStatsMB = heapStats;
  for (const key in heapStatsMB) {
    heapStatsMB[key] = `${(((heapStatsMB[key] / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)} MB`;
  }
  console.log('');
  console.log(message);
  console.table(heapStatsMB);
  console.log('');
};
```

```
before find orders
┌─────────────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│           (index)           │    Values    │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────────┤
│       total_heap_size       │  '54.05 MB'  │
│ total_heap_size_executable  │  '0.80 MB'   │
│     total_physical_size     │  '53.71 MB'  │
│    total_available_size     │ '1999.10 MB' │
│       used_heap_size        │  '49.56 MB'  │
│       heap_size_limit       │ '2048.00 MB' │
│       malloced_memory       │  '0.01 MB'   │
│    peak_malloced_memory     │  '2.48 MB'   │
│      does_zap_garbage       │  '0.00 MB'   │
│  number_of_native_contexts  │  '0.00 MB'   │
│ number_of_detached_contexts │  '0.00 MB'   │
└─────────────────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

```
afters find orders
┌─────────────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│           (index)           │    Values    │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────────┤
│       total_heap_size       │ '521.66 MB'  │
│ total_heap_size_executable  │  '1.05 MB'   │
│     total_physical_size     │ '520.90 MB'  │
│    total_available_size     │ '1611.12 MB' │
│       used_heap_size        │ '435.79 MB'  │ // <---435 after Orders.find
│       heap_size_limit       │ '2048.00 MB' │
│       malloced_memory       │  '0.01 MB'   │
│    peak_malloced_memory     │  '2.93 MB'   │
│      does_zap_garbage       │  '0.00 MB'   │
│  number_of_native_contexts  │  '0.00 MB'   │
│ number_of_detached_contexts │  '0.00 MB'   │
└─────────────────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

```
memory info
┌─────────────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│           (index)           │    Values    │
├─────────────────────────────┼──────────────┤
│       total_heap_size       │ '521.66 MB'  │
│ total_heap_size_executable  │  '1.05 MB'   │
│     total_physical_size     │ '520.90 MB'  │
│    total_available_size     │ '1610.56 MB' │
│       used_heap_size        │ '436.35 MB'  │ // <--- stays around 435
│       heap_size_limit       │ '2048.00 MB' │
│       malloced_memory       │  '0.01 MB'   │
│    peak_malloced_memory     │  '2.93 MB'   │
│      does_zap_garbage       │  '0.00 MB'   │
│  number_of_native_contexts  │  '0.00 MB'   │
│ number_of_detached_contexts │  '0.00 MB'   │
└─────────────────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: if you do `let j = await Order.find({});` instead, do you still have the same issue? I wouldn't be surprised if Node is leaving that in memory as a `const`. At least with `let j` you would be able to `j = null;` when you are done with the mongo data to ensure the garbage collector clears the memory. Also, I started having issues like this on a big project I was doing... I switched to C.

Comment: changed it to `let` but it looks like I still have the issue.

Comment: Can you try adding `j.length = 0` after `v8Print('afters find orders');`. And then check the output

Comment: V8 will only GC if it needs to; try forcing GC by running `node --expose-gc server.js`. Then, before you read the memory usage, call `global.gc()`

Comment: @CharchitKapoor setting `j.length` to `0` didn't fixed the issue, unless I called  global.gc() as Richard suggested. Note to others, calling global.gc() too much might impact performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 will only GC if it needs to free up space. By default Node is given ~2GB of memory so it's not under much pressure from your 435mb of objects.

You can force a GC by running your server as `node --expose-gc server.js` which exposes a `gc` function on the global.

```js
const v8 = require('v8');

// for memory allocation heap debugging
module.exports.v8Print = (message) => {
  global.gc(); // <-- Call this before reading heap info
  const heapStats = v8.getHeapStatistics();
  const heapStatsMB = heapStats;
  for (const key in heapStatsMB) {
    heapStatsMB[key] = `${(((heapStatsMB[key] / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)} MB`;
  }
  console.log('');
  console.log(message);
  console.table(heapStatsMB);
  console.log('');
};

// ...

app.get('/orders', async (req, res, next) => {
  v8Print('before find orders'); // ~50MB
  let j = await Order.find({}); // Use `let` merely so we can set it to `undefined` later
  v8Print('afters find orders'); // ~435MB
  j = undefined; // Remove reference so it can be GC'd
  v8Print('afters clean up'); // ~50MB
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
app.get('/logMem', async (req, res, next) => {
  v8Print('memory info'); // ~50MB
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: "By default Node is given ~2GB of memory so it's not under much pressure from your 435mb of objects." It still doesn't get cleared if I set my heap limit (`--max-old-space-size`) to 435mb for example. It does go down a little- to 306 mb- but not back down to 50mb. It that normal? This would eventually cause memory allocation errors on a heroku dyno.

Comment: Calling global.gc() worked but but you're not supposed to do that too often because it can impact performance, correct?

Comment: Yeh definitely don't do that in production, global.gc should only be used to test you're correctly releasing memory. You can trust V8 will GC when appropriate. Perhaps try executing /orders/ 10+ times in series (not concurrently) and you'll see your server won't crash. Of course if you get 10+ concurrent requests there's a chance it will crash as each requests needs at least 435mb which is unwise.

Comment: If you really have to serve all orders to the client in a single request (i.e. pagination isn't suitable), you're better off streaming the data down; something like `Order.find({}).cursor({ transform: JSON.stringify }).pipe(res)` as that way it doesn't hold every order in memory at once. i.e. it can GC each individual document as soon as it's been sent to the client.